# Solution to this Geometric Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$2^n  \sum_{i=0}^{\log(n)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^i$$

I did the following:

$S = 1 + (3/2) + (3/2)^2 + \cdots + (3/2)^n$

$rS = (3/2) + (3/2)^2 + \cdots + (3/2)^n+1$

$S - rS = 1 - (3/2)^n+1$

$\Rightarrow -(1/2)S =1 - (3/2)^{n+1} \Rightarrow S = -2 - (3/2)^n+1 = 2^n((3/2)^{n+1} + 2)$

Is this correct?

Comment: no. Instead of $2^n((3/2)^{n+1} + 2)$ it _should_ be 2^n((3/2)^{\log(n)+1} + 2). Check the upper bound on the summation.

Comment: @Sabyasachi:  That should be an answer.  There is the problem that $\log(n)$ is not a natural all the time... (and what base of $\log$?)

Comment: @RossMillikan I am assuming $e$. Although why not just leave it as it is if we don't know the base. Although, I came across a similar expression once in my computer science class, it was base 2, (because of binary)

Comment: @Sabyasachi:  people post questions assuming various bases for the $\log$ function.  $2, e, 10$ are all popular.  Whatever it is, the upper limit of a sum needs to be a natural.  Presumably there is a floor function to fix that.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes a floor. He probably didn't know the LaTex syntax.

Comment: @Sabyasachi: Maybe it is a $\LaTeX$ problem, but often it is not recognizing that there needs to be a floor.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13362/discussion-between-sabyasachi-and-ross-millikan)

Comment: weird, I tried to remove that dialog. ugh. anyway @RossMillikan see my answer. Anything to add/change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum^t_{i=0} \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^i = 2\times\left(\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{t+1}-1\right)$$

In your case $t=\lfloor \log(n) \rfloor$(Presumably, because as Ross points out $t \in \mathbb N$)

Substitute, and you're done.